# dropdown menu pushing down content. max-height toggle

Tags: html, css, sass, navigation

I'm toggling a class of open to change the max height of my UL element to show and hide the nav.

I'm not completely understanding why but this line

```
.navbar--upper,
.navbar--lower {
    height: 50px;
}
```

is screwing with the content not bring pushed down.

I have included a jsfiddle link to demonstrate this
https://jsfiddle.net/h1hpLvs3/
Probably a really simple explanation but can someone shine some light?

Also, if there is a better way to do this please feel free to add some constructive criticism or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'min-height: 50px' does not have the same result.  The child elements are 'overflowing' the parent container with a fixed height, giving you some options to handle them. Like hiding those elements if you'd like.  Min height allows the parent to expand with the children.  It is the parent container which pushes it's siblings down.

for likely desired effect?

```
.navbar--upper,
.navbar--lower {
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

fixed height but hide the children, (keep them safe from danger) **just for example**

```
.navbar--upper,
.navbar--lower {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the second option is no good as the overflow:hidden hides my list items when opened, but the first option works, do I even need the height/min-height declaration on the .navbar? should I set to auto or just remove it? @Kosch

Comment: the second option was just to show overflow with the fixed height.  not sure how the rest of the page is supposed to look.  beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  i try not to add anything i don't need though.